# video player for HTML 5 page not loading

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm using [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/#setup) to as my video player for a project I've been working on. Basically I have a div, and I wanted to have the video player within that div, however when I load the page nothing happens, and the video is never played. In fact, the video is never loaded nor shown in the page. I basically copied  the example from VideoJS' page. Any thoughts?

```
 <div class="video-js-box">
            <!-- Using the Video for Everybody Embed Code http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody -->
         <div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 600px; display:none">
            <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  
              controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"  
              poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"  
              data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>  
             <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4'></source>
             <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm'>></source>  
             <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg'></source>  
            </video>
            <!-- Download links provided for devices that can't play video in the browser. -->
            <p class="vjs-no-video"><strong>Download Video:</strong>
              <a href="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4">MP4</a>,
              <a href="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm">WebM</a>,
              <a href="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv">Ogg</a><br>
              <!-- Support VideoJS by keeping this link. -->
              <a href="http://videojs.com">HTML5 Video Player</a> by VideoJS
            </p>
          </div>    
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div><!--main-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your div display:none. So even after the player is loadin, the div it resides in, was being hidden. Change your div from `<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 600px; display:none"> to <div style="position: absolute; top: 50px;">` to display the player properly!

working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/YsXTu/1/

```
<div class="video-js-box">
        <!-- Using the Video for Everybody Embed Code http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody -->
     <div style="position: absolute; top: 50px;">
        <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"  
          controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"  
          poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"  
          data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>  
         <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4'></source>
         <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm'>></source>  
         <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg'></source>  
        </video>
        <!-- Download links provided for devices that can't play video in the browser. -->
        <p class="vjs-no-video"><strong>Download Video:</strong>
          <a href="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4">MP4</a>,
          <a href="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm">WebM</a>,
          <a href="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv">Ogg</a><br>
          <!-- Support VideoJS by keeping this link. -->
          <a href="http://videojs.com">HTML5 Video Player</a> by VideoJS
        </p>
      </div>    
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div><!--main-->​
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across another problem. video.js removes any onload functions in the hosting page. So if you have an onload call in either  or window.onload then it won't fire.